# What's the difference between "you wasted" and "you've wasted"

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

I've got a question about this topic. So, about the context. I've just watched a video and in the end, the author said thank you as follows:

> Thank you for all the time you wasted on this video.

I wonder if instead it could or should be

> Thank you for all the time you have wasted on this video.

Which is more suitable in this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Present perfect or past simple - "the best movie I (saw/'ve seen) this year"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258527/present-perfect-or-past-simple-the-best-movie-i-saw-ve-seen-this-year). Even better, switch to  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) and have a look at [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are grammatically correct and it just boils down to which one you choose to use.

Comment: i know that they're both correct, but which one is more suitable?

Comment: “You wasted” is better here because it’s more informal, which it should be because it’s ironic or humorous.